# How to Swap UIBarbuttons when editing a UItextview

Tags: uitextview, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I'm making a notes app for learning purposes and I'm having an issue with the UIBarButtons.

**The Problem**

When I tap the textview to begin editing, I want the right barbutton to change to "Done" such that the user can dismiss the keyboard with it (and autosave in the background). My problem is getting the button to turn back to my original rightbarbutton after the user presses "Done".

**What I've tried so far**

I've tried making the original position a property of the view but it seems to me that the storyboard represents the barbuttons as positions rather than actual entities. So this was unsuccessful as I only get a blank spot when I try.

I've looked all over for an answer but I didn't get one. Help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right in the `UIBarButtonItem` aren't views, they are just objects describing views. So setting a frame or center on them isn't possible.

What you'll need to do is create two `UIBarButtonItems` one for edit and one for done. Then using the `UIToolBar` methods or properties, you'll need to remove the edit button, but hold on to it for later, and insert the done button in its place. When finished reverse the swap.

You can grab a `UIToolBar`'s items by `toolbar.items`, it will be an `NSArray`. Then you can `removeObjectAtIndex:` to remove the edit button. Then you can `insertObject:atIndex:` to add your done button. Then back to your `UIToolBar` for `setItems:animated`.

```
// Get current items
NSMutableArray *temp = [toolBar.items mutableCopy];

// Check for editing, with your own variable, then insert/remove buttons
if (/*Editing*/) {
    [temp removeObject:editButton];
    [temp insertObject:doneButton atIndex:0];
} else {
    [temp removeObject:doneButton];
    [temp insertObject:editButton atIndex:0];
}

// Send back to your toolbar
[toolBar setItems:temp animated:YES];
```

Comment: Will this still work if I used a custom button in the uibarbutton? How can I move all the details(backgrnd image etc.) over to code when I'm implementing the swap?

Comment: It will work just fine regardless of what you've done to the UIBarButtonItem. All you need to do is hold on to it as a variable or property so it doesn't get released.

Comment: Not yet.. It looks like the navigation controller is ignoring that snippet. Is there some other link I should have made to facilitate this?

Comment: Well it seems odd that the navigation controller would own your toolbar. Are you sure its not your viewController that owns the toolbar?

Comment: yeah It seems it's my viewController that owns the toolbar. How do i access that then? I noticed I only have the "self.toolBarItems" option but no "self.toolbar"

Comment: Well its up to you to connect it since you're using storyboards. So create a property for it named toolbar, then you could do self.toolbar.items

Comment: Hey Ryan been a while :) I was finally able to access that property using the self.toolbar.rightBarButton property. However, when it comes to swapping back to my original button (the one with a round rect button inserted), I get: reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil' error.

Is there any way to create a UI bar button and insert a rect button with a custom image into it? that way I could just bypass the storyboard altogether. What do you think?

Comment: Found the documentation with the needed code. Anyone interested in the final answer can check here: http://pastebin.com/mSpfbZdW

Comment: Glad you got it together! Happy Coding (Down with Storyboards!) :)